# Многопоточная обработка очереди. Общение между потоками

Tags: java, многопоточность, парсер

Написал парсер для парсинга запросов в гугле. Все отлично работает,но так как гугл быстро стреляет капчей, использую прокси.

Есть свой список проксей. В текущем варианте прокси меняются по очереди. Это занимает достаточно большое кол-во времени, учитывая что отклик в среднем занимает 5-10 секунд.

Вот о чем подумал, что нужно организовать это на нескольких потоках, но не пойму как сделать общение между потоками, пока тестирую только такой вариант(он не дает нужной скорости, хотя и в десятки раз быстрей однопоточного):

- Есть очередь с запросами(далее ЗАП) и коллекция для записи результатов.
- Есть лист с очередями проксей для каждого потока.
- Далее запускаются все потоки с первым элементом из ЗАП, и пытаются спарсить результат. (если первый прокси не сработал, из очереди берется второй и так далее)
- Когда какой либо из потоков приносит положительный результат, он останавливает все потоки, потом записывает результат, удаляет из ЗАП обработанный элемент.
- Происходит итерация и все продолжается по кругу. Количество потоков зависит от кол-ва очередей с проксями.

Можно ли организовать это по другому, для ускорения работы программы? А то странное чувство, что что-то тут не так...

Comment: вы пытаетесь натравить несколько потоков для выполнения одной и той же задачи?

Comment: Именно, так как это пока это самый быстрый вариант, который корректно работает

Comment: ну тогда вы выбрали правильный путь, в любом случае у вас будет точка синхронизации, которая должна в случае успеха остановить текущую работу.

Comment: Да, все синхронизировано между собой. Меня смущает постоянное создание потоков. К примеру если у меня 10 000 запросов, которые необходимо спарсить и на это 5 потоков, по ходу выполнения программы будет создано и завершено 50 000 потоков

Comment: а, это не хорошо. Каждый поток создаст процесс в ОС, планировщик задолбается их переключать, так вы сокращаете производительность системы. А эти 10к запросов независимы же?

Comment: Да. Я по началу делил список запросов на части для каждого потока, но случилась такая проблема, что в одном из потоков закончились рабочие прокси,  а у другого половину осталось не используемых. В итоге пришлось сделать очередь и передавать каждый запрос каждому потоку, и только после успешной обработки фиксировать результат

Comment: Так, смотрите, количество потоков необходимо подбирать исходя из системы, если у вас 4 ядра с 2 логическими потоками на каждое ядро, то максимум выбирайте 8 потоков, далее, мне кажнтся вам нужны 2 блокирующих очереди, в первую очередь записывайте запросы, во вторую прокси. Если запрос не удался, записывайте обратно в очередь, чтобы он снова выполнился.

Comment: Да, спасибо за совет, все примерно так и работает, единственное что я сразу делю прокси на очереди для каждого потока. Потоков как раз таки использую 8( по Фрейду)))) ). Проблема пересоздавания потоков остается.
Я себе это представляю примерно так: Потоки обрабатывают первый элемент. Какой то из потоков обработал его и говорит другим, давай те работать со следующим элементом и так далее. Тогда не будет пересозданий потоков, но я вообще не представляю как это можно реализовать

Comment: ну так для этого и создаются блокирующие очереди, они в единственном экземпляре, каждый поток имеет к ним доступ, но выполнить операцию может только один из них, который захватил их в данный момент, остальные ждут.

Comment: Я понял, сейчас подумаю, как это можно будет применить. Единственное что - все потоки должны работать одновременно, иначе если разные потоки будут по очереди обрабатывать, получиться примерно то же самое,что и с одним потоком, или возможно я плохо понял, в любом случае мысли куда копать, появились

Answer (score 3):

Вот так они и будут работать одновременно:

```
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Request> requests; 
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Proxy> proxies;
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Result> results;

public static void main(String[] args){
    fillRequestQueue(requests); //заполнение очереди запросами
    fillProxyQueue(proxies);

    runThreads();
}

public void runThreads(){
  for(int i = 0; i<8; ++i){
    new Thread(()->{
     if(requests.isEmpty()){ //Если запросы закончились, закончить выполнение
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        return;
     }
     Request req = requests.take();
     Proxy proxy = proxies.take();
     Result res = req.execute(proxy);
     if(res.isFailed()){
        requests.add(req); //Запрос нужно будет выполнить повторно
      } else {
        results.add(res);
      }
    }).start();
  }
}
```

P.S. Код является скорее псевдокодом для отражения мысли, не компилировал его.

Comment: Спасибо! Когда адаптирую, отпишусь о результатах!

Comment: Все, до меня дошло! Это отличный вариант!) Прям озарение. Не могу только плюсик поставить, репутации мало(

Comment: Переживу без него  :)